# Can Add-Type -AssemblyName be made to respect AssemblyFolders or AssemblyFoldersEx

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

You can make your non-GACed references show up in the Visual Studio Add Reference dialog by putting the assembly paths in one of the following registry entries:

```
[HKLM|HKLU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\<version>\AssemblyFoldersEx\
[HKLM|HKLU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\
```

The second version does not work in VS.2010 and seems to be deprecated. Is there any way to Get Add-Type to respect this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell this cannot be done. As such I opened a [feature request](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/649443/powershell-should-attempt-to-resolve-generic-overloads-of-nongeneric-types-like-c) on connect to allow for this in some cases.